# Jquery event of replaced class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a Hide/Show button with jQuery. When .cminus is clicked, it needs to hide .arrowwrap and .commentbody and replace it's own class with cplus. Then if .cplus is clicked opposite needs to happen.

Problem 1: In example below after .cminus is replaced with .cplus, the .cplus does not fire click event when it's clicked.

(EDIT problem 2 moved to separate ticket)
Problem 2: I'm not reaching the .commentbody right to hide/show it

Html:

```
<div class="commentline">
    <div class="carrowholder">
        <div class="cminus"></div>
        <div class="arrowwrap">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentholder">
        <div class="commenttitle">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="commentbody">
            Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.cminus').click(function(e) {
  $(this).next('.arrowwrap').hide();
  $(this).parent().next('.commentholder .commentbody').hide();
  $(this).removeClass('cminus');
  $(this).addClass('cplus');
})

$('.cplus').click(function(e) {
  alert("clicked cplus");
  $(this).next('.arrowwrap').show();
  $(this).addClass('cminus');
  $(this).removeClass('cplus');
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.toggleClass('cminus');` etc. and then have one event handler OR use .on/.live on the parent element to allow for delegated events.

As for

```
$(this).parent().next('.commentholder .commentbody').hide();
```

I think the .commentholder is redundant as you're specifying next which gets the next sibling.

Comment: Regarding problem 1. Do replaced classes not get recognized? Can you expand on your solution? And removing .commentholder does not fix the second issue.

Comment: If you add a class post binding, that event will not be bound to that element unless you're using delegated events.

Comment: Got it. Fixed the first issue with single event listener. Still wondering about the second though

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as resolution and opening separate ticket for problem 2. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to toggle between showing and hiding I suggest using .toggle('showorhide')

I've created a basic fiddle for you to try.

http://jsfiddle.net/LsWuR/2/

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I can not use $('.commentbody'). directly as there are many in the document and I need specifically parent->.commenthoder->.commentbody

Comment: Did a quick update to be relative. Should be what you're looking for http://jsfiddle.net/LsWuR/2/