# Can not reach specific element in hierarchy

Tags: jquery

I can not directly user $('commentbody') because there are many comments and selection needs to be done withing this specific area.

Html:

```
<div class="commentline">
    <div class="carrowholder">
        <div class="ctoggle"></div>
        <div class="arrowwrap">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentholder">
        <div class="commenttitle">
            Title
        </div>
        <div class="commentbody">
            Body
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ctoggle').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next('.commentholder > .commentbody').hide();
})
```

Comment: well, you're going to have to have unique IDs for divs if you want to access them uniquely.

Comment: Duplicate:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058645/jquery-event-of-replaced-class

Comment: @Geoist I split the question in two, since issues are different.

Comment: @FlavorScape Is there no way to select it otherwise? Just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt fails because you are looking for a *sibling* of the parent element that matches the selector:

```
.commentholder > .commentbody
```

No sibling is ever going to match that (`.commentholder` is a sibling, but you're looking for a child of that), so you need to move the child selector out. You can use [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (or [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)):

```
$('.ctoggle').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next().children('.commentbody').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is commentbody not a sibling of Commentholder? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @DavidW - No problem, glad I could help :) To answer your comment, no, `.commentbody` is a *child* of `.commentholder`. A sibling is an element in the same branch of the tree. A child is one level deeper.

Comment: Oh, right. Thanks. I think I had a temporary brain freeze, for some reason when I was thinking of "sibling" I thought of "child" not sure why :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.ctoggle').click(function(e) {
    $(this).parent().next().find('.commentbody').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the API documentation: "Get the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector."

So, your selector matches a child of the sibling, ergo you will receive nothing. Try:

```
var x = $(this).parent().next('.commentholder');
x.find('.commentbody').hide();
```

(this works in your example)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
[include jQuery here]
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="commentline">
    <div class="carrowholder">
        <div class="ctoggle">Click to toggle</div>
        <div class="arrowwrap">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentholder">
        <div class="commenttitle">
            Title 1
        </div>
        <div class="commentbody">
            Body 1
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="commentline">
    <div class="carrowholder">
        <div class="ctoggle">Click to toggle</div>
        <div class="arrowwrap">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="commentholder">
        <div class="commenttitle">
            Title 2
        </div>
        <div class="commentbody">
            Body 2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This Javascript will work:

```
$('.ctoggle').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.commentline').find('.commentbody').toggle();
});
```

What this does is find the first element up in the DOM which has the class `.commentline`(which is the parent of all the DIVs for a comment), and then it finds all the elements further down in that branch of the DOM tree which have the class `.commentbody`, which is fine in this case since each commentline only has one commentbody. If there were more `.commentbody` DIVs in each `.commentline`DIV then you would need to specify further which one (using `.first()` or `.find()` again etc.).

There are other solutions already mentioned, but I find this kind of approach to be slightly more readable, and thus maintainable - but that's my opinion :O)